# Safe Array - Set count zero

Tags: c++, com, atl

will the following code work, if the safe array count to be returned is zero? Should I do anything else?

```
HRESULT GetAlarms(FAULT_TYPE eAlarmType, long alarmLevel, VARIANT* pvarAlamLst)
{
   pvarAlamLst->vt = VT_ARRAY |VT_VARIANT;
   pvarAlamLst->parray = NULL;
   return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pArray` is a `LPSAFEARRAY` and should be treated as such. Therefore you need the `SAFEARRAY` functions (macros). `SAFEARRAY` doesn't have a concept of "count" as such, it's a variable-dimension array. A one-dimensional `SAFEARRAY` can have size 0, but a 2D `SAFEARRAY` would have size 0x0 (or 1x0).

In particular, MSDN documents `VT_ARRAY` as "The pointer in `parray` points to an array descriptor", but `NULL` doesn't point to an array descriptor.